# How to auto populate a field base on another

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have tried to Google a simple way to auto fill the name of the Manager of the user that is picked in the people picker. For me it seems to be a straight forward thing to do, but all the posts I find about the issues, either include code or are just very complicated to set up.

All I want it to do, is when I pick a user in the people picker, it should populate another field with the manager for the user.

I have already set up a Data connection for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a **SharePoint Designer workflow**?

You can create a workflow which will be triggered when a new item is created and retrieves the manager from an associated list containing, for example two columns (User, Manager) where you can map the User and the Manager.

The con of this approach is that you will need to save the form (so the workflow is started) in order to get the manager associated to the record.

**Another approach**
You can also consider a lookup column in your first list which allows you to select a user from the second list (same list as you would create for the workflow). Then you can include the manager field as well by checking the checkbox. However, this also will not display the manager in the form straight away, you first have to save the record.

If you need any help, please let me know.